# Dynamic prepared statement (bind param error)

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I'm trying to be able to add parameters to to my prepared statement, query and arrays look right. But the "Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables" error is triggered.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `feed` ';
$types = array();
$params = array();

if( isset($_GET['p']) ) {
  $page = $_GET['p'];
}
else {
  $page = 0;
}

if( isset($_GET['q']) ) {
  $sql .= 'WHERE `title` LIKE ? ';
  $search = $_GET['q'];
  array_push($types, 's');
  array_push($params, $search);
}

$sql .= 'ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT ?, 6';

array_push($types, 'i');
array_push($params, $page);

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$params = array_merge($types, $params);

$refs = array();
foreach($params as $key => $value)
  $refs[$key] = &$params[$key];

call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $refs);
```

(Printed from the server)

Query: SELECT * FROM `feed` WHERE `title` LIKE ? ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT ?, 6

Array merge:

```
Array
(
    [0] => s
    [1] => i
    [2] => word
    [3] => 0
)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that the first parameter 'types' is a **string** of the types of the parameters, not an array. so the the parameter list for the example should look like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => si
    [1] => word
    [2] => 0
)
```

This is untested code: but implode should do what we want from the '$types' array

```
$strTypes = implode('', $types);
```

i will check it later.